# Is it possible/easy to display a background image and text for an empty table view?

Tags: ios

I have a requirement to display a table view if there are items to display, otherwise to display a splash screen which contains an image and some text.

Is it possible to display the image and text as a background for there table which is displayed when the table is empty, and otherwise is not displayed and its just the table rows?

If it is possible then is this approach "better" or "worse" than having a separate controller for the splash screen with a higher level controller decided whether to use the splash controller or table controller depending upon the number of items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a view controller that contains the splash screen/text as the background with the table view positioned on top of the splash screen.  Then when you load the data for the table view, if there is no data, hide the table view (which will show the splashscreen).  If there is data, size the table view so it completely covers the splash screen/text.

Comment: I would maybe add to hide or change the background image when the table loads so it doesn't peek out from behind the table when you pull down past the header/footer.

Answer (score 3):

What works for me is to add a hidden **UIImageView** as a subview of the table

```
[noResultsView setHidden:YES];
[tableView insertSubview:noResultsView belowSubview:aSearchBar];
```

which is toggled depending on the number of rows that the table has:

```
[noResultsView setHidden:[arrayOfObjects count]];
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way of doing it would be to set your splash screen as the tableHeaderView if the number of table row is zero.